# How can I join a prefix Id like pat_XXXXXXXX to ObjectID(XXXXXXX) in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join

I am trying to get the email address from an patient table in mongoDB compass and I need to join it with an patientId in the orders collection that looks like `patientId : "pat_XXXXXXX"` to the ID in the Orders collection that looks like `_id : ObjectId('XXXXXXXX')`. The problem I have is when I do a $lookup function the array returns null.

```
{ 
  "$lookup": {
  "from": "patients",
  "localField": "patientId",
  "foreignField": "_id",
  "as": "patients"
}}
```

Then when I tried to use the function $toObjectId to change the patientId to an Object like this `{ "addFields": { "userObjectId": { "$toObjectId": "patientId" }}}`, I get the error `Failed to optimize pipeline :: caused by :: Failed to parse objectId 'patientId' in $convert with no onError value: Invalid string length for parsing to OID, expected 24 but found 9`. The patientId length is 24 characters after the pat_ part so I think that is what the problem is. Is there a way to join an Id with a prefix to an ObjectId?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by doing the following,
Go to the Patients Collection and choose the aggregations section.

Click add stage and Choose the option $addFields, then create a variable patientId where you covert the Object Id to string and concatenate pat_ the front of the Id.

```
{patient_Id: {$concat : ["pat_", {$toString : "$_id"}]}}
```

Then add another stage and choose the option $lookup. This will connect the two collections of the patients and orders. This can be done using the following

```
{
  from: 'orders',
  localField: 'patient_Id',
  foreignField: 'patientId',
  as: 'orders'
}
```

Add another stage $unwind this will unpack the orders collection allowing you to use the variables there.

```
{
  path: "$orders" 
}
```